# Numerical methods for Non linear ode with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I have the non-linear ODE

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y=a(y+y^3)$$

With the boundary conditions that 
$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} y(x) =0$

I found that it has an analytical solution of the form $\sqrt{\coth^2(\sqrt{a} x )-1 } $. 
My main goal is to get this solution numerically. 
The exact solution  has singularity at the origin so no numerical method will work for it but the singularity is of the order $1/x$ so I made the substitution $ u=x^2 y $ which eliminates the singularity at the origin.In the new equation numerical methods do apply. But now I am stuck I don't know which method is used for odes with infinite boundary conditions. The only idea that I have is that I make the solution close to 0 at the end points of my the discrete domain I choose but I am not aware of any numerical for solving this nonlinear odes of this form. .Also it would be great if someone could recommend a book that covers odes of this form.

Comment: Since your solution goes to $\infty$ as $x \to 0$, it is not a solution on $\mathbb R$ but only on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ (separately).  On the other hand, if $f(x)$ is your solution, $f(x+c)$ is also a solution (except at its singularity $x=-c$) that satisfies the same boundary conditions.  So your boundary conditions do not determine a solution.

Comment: Obviously, the solution you are looking for is $y=0$. As that is a hyperbolic saddle-point, there will be no other solutions with this asymptotic behavior.